# How to apply tf.data transformations to a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow

I want to apply tf.data transformations to a panda  dataframe. According to the tensorflow docs [HERE](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/pandas_dataframe) I can apply tf.data to a dataframe directly but the dtype of the dataframe should be uniform.

When I apply tf.data to my dataframe like below

```
tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(df['reports'])
```

it generates this error

```
ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type float).
```

When I print `df['reports'].dtype` it is `dtype('O')` which seems to be not uniformed, if this is the case then how can I convert this dataframe to uniform `dtype`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a ragged structure:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'reports': [[2.0, 3.0, 4.0], [2.0, 3.0], [2.0]]})

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tf.ragged.constant(df['reports']))

for x in dataset:
  print(x)
```

```
tf.Tensor([2. 3. 4.], shape=(3,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([2. 3.], shape=(2,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([2.], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try forcing your `df["reports"]` to a specific type. Assuming that you want to convert this column to numbers you can easily do it like this:

```
df['reports'] = pd.to_numeric(df['reports'])
```

Anyway, I suggest you to investigate the cause of your non-uniform `dtype('O')`. You could have some mistake in your data.

Comment: It gives an error like `ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type float)`. But when I do like this `df['findings'].astype(str)` then it works. I don't know why but I have run my code like this.

Comment: Maybe this will do it `np.asarray(pd.to_numeric(df['reports'])).astype('float32')` @albert

Comment: Is it ok to go with just `df['findings'].astype(str)` or I should try this `np.asarray(pd.to_numeric(df['reports'])).astype('float32')`?

Comment: I think that maybe `df['findings'].astype(str)` works because, when the vector is changed to a tensor, then the conversion to a 'float32' is done automatically. Surely the tensors are numerical @albert

Comment: Please, if one of the answers solved your problem, remember to accept it by toggling the check mark besides it. See [what to do when someone answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)